# OneSignal Chrome multiple notification

Tags: c#, onesignal

I have some problem with web push notification.
I'm able to send the notification regularly, but, when I send two notification and the first is still visible on the screen, the second overwrite the first one.

The REST API is called by an MVC site written with C#, the object I send is the following:

```
var obj = new
        {
            app_id = _appKey,
            contents = new { en = message },
            headings = new { en = title },
            included_segments = new[] { "All" },
            url,
            chrome_web_icon = imageUrl,
            priority = 1,
            id = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
        };
```

Did anyone experienced the same issue? 
How can I solve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got this answer from OneSignal person.

When using our `REST API` to programmatically send notifications, you can use the undocumented parameter `web_push_topic`.

In a set of notifications sharing the same `web_push_topic`, newly received notifications will replace older received notifications with the same topic. Only notifications sharing the same topic will be replaced; notifications without a topic or with a different topic will not be replaced. You can set different topics for different sets of notifications to control which notifications stay on screen.

The `web_push_topic` value can be any string value.

On Chrome, a maximum of 3 notifications is displayed at any time, even if the other notifications are not related to your site or from OneSignal. This means you can only show 3 categories of notifications to your user, not counting for other notifications that might be displayed at that time.
On Firefox on Windows, many more notifications can be shown at a time (6+).

On Firefox on Mac, and Safari on Mac, only one notification can be shown at a time, even if the other notifications are not related to your site or from OneSignal. Notifications also disappear quickly within 5 seconds and this time is not customizable.

On Chrome/Firefox on Android, multiple notifications can be shown at a time.

If you do not specify `web_push_topic` , each notification will be replaced by a newer notification. If you do specify `web_push_topic`, you can choose which notifications will be replaced and which notifications will stack.

When sending a notification using our API, setting a string value for web_push_topic will set the topic for the notification. Any notifications sharing the same topic will replace each other, but any notifications with a different topic won't be replaced.

So suppose you send 4 notifications:

1. Notification "Open house at 1234 Street at 3 PM this Saturday" with topic 'open-houses'.
2. Notification "Open house at 1234 Street changed to 4 PM this Saturday" with topic 'open-houses'.
3. Notification "20 new houses match your criteria in the Seattle, WA" with topic 'general-updates'.
4. Notification "Find an agent in your area" with topic 'promotional'.

The sequence of notifications observed will be:

1. Notification #1 shows.
2. Notification #2 replaces #1 (even if docked in Mac OS X's notification tray).
3. Notification #3 is shown separately (and if docked in Mac OS X's notification tray, it will use a separate entry).
4. Notification #4 is also shown separately.
   In the end, when the subscriber checks his unread notifications, he will see three total notifications.

Example Code:

```
payload = {"app_id": "5eb5a37e-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c",
           "include_player_ids": ["6392d91a-b206-4b7b-a620-cd68e32c3a76"],
           "contents": {"en": "English Message"},
           "web_push_topic": 'Unique for every notification'}
```

Comment: The best answer

Answer (score 0):

OneSignal intentionally implements notification replacement that results in this behavior.

The reason for this is to avoid cases where a subscriber could end up with up to 100 notifications to dismiss from a single website, which would be a terrible experience for them.

In the future OneSignal may allow you to avoid this limitation, but in most cases we wouldn't recommend doing this differently.